# PHP - mysqli - Export cvs file prints on page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, fputcsv

I am trying to export a .csv file from mysql query. 
When I uncomment the headers it shows the error: 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/9/a/8/localhost/httpd.www/name/wp-includes/functions.php:3508)'.

In both ways the script is printing the results on the page and I am not getting the file downloaded on my computer.

Any suggestions?

html:

```
form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="export_list_form" > 

<input type="submit" name="exp_list_send" value="download" /></br>
</form>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['exp_list_send'])){
    //header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output_download = fopen('php://output/', 'w');

    fputcsv($output_download, array('User ID', 'User Name', 'Password'));

    $rows_download = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE 1');

    while ($row_download = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows_download)) {
      fputcsv($output_download, $row_download);
    }
    fclose($output_download);

    //exit();   
}
```

Comment: You cannot send headers after printing something on the screen. Is this your complete php file? If not please show us the rest of the file.

Comment: I think the problem is because wordpress is sending already the headers. Need to find a way to change that